# Angular2 RC1 update control value in controlGroup

Tags: angular

I have created a form using NgForm and added some controls to it. The form is used for a basic chat proof of concept.

When a user sends a message I need to reset the value of the message input to be empty so it's ready for them to begin typing their next message. However I can't find any documentation or information on how I might update the value of the control.

I've tried various things but nothing is working...

Here's some things I've tried.

```
sendMessage(formValues) {
    formValues.message = ''; // This works but the view doesn't update so there is evidently no binding or observers attached.
    formValues.message.value = ''; // This throws an error that type string doesn't value defined
    formValues.message.val(''); // This throws an error that type string doesn't contain a method val()
    formValues['message'] = '' // This works but the view doesn't get updated so there is evidently no binding/observers here.
    formValues.message.updateValue(''); // This also throws an error that type string doesn't have a updateValue() method.
}
```

Heres the view template:

```
<form name='chat-form' (ngSubmit)='sendMessage(messageForm.value)' #messageForm='ngForm'>
    <input class='message-body' ngControl='message' placeholder='Enter your message'/>
    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>
```

There must be a way to do such a basic fundamental action on a form such as updating the value from the controller or model, but so far I've come up dry.

Comment: formValues is a ControlGroup?

Comment: Yes, I've added the view template code above to show how the ControlGroup is created via the ngForm directive

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the `ControlGroup`, when you try to get a `Control` from it,  wants to return a value of type `AbstractControl`which lacks the function `updateValue()`

If you cast it to a `Control` it should work.  e.g.

```
(<Control>yourControlGroup.controls['some_form_field']).updateValue('new value');
```

In your case, perhaps the following would work assuming `formValues` is of the type `ControlGroup` (if not please specify what it is):

```
(<Control>formValues.controls['message']).updateValue('')
```

or perhaps

```
(<Control>formValues['message']).updateValue('')
```